# Conflicting jquery script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have here an html page that uses bootstrap and javascript as well as jquery.

```
  <html>
    <body>
    
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="query1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#query" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="query">
        Query/Concern/Suggestions
      </button>
    
    <div class="collapse" id="query">
      <div class="card card-body">
    sample
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="button" id="order1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#order" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="order">
        Advanced Order or For Delivery
      </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="order">
      <div class="card card-body">
      sample
      </div>
    </div>

<! ––pera-padala button ––>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="pera-padala1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pera-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pera-padala">
    Smart Pera Padala
  </button>

<! ––pera-padala ––>
<div class="collapse" id="pera-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
  <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSeRxBdj_mH5afO7UGT9fb_o02sSbsFVf6LduIXH_3bRzYJsKg/formResponse">

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. Input ang Account Number ng Smart Padala na inyong papadalan.(Magsulat lamang ng 11 digits kung cellphone number at 16 digits kung account number</span>
       
      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala  </span>
        <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-bayad"  type="number"  required="">
      </div>
      <br>
       <div class="form-element">
              <span>C. Total Babayaran: <span id="padala-result"></span> Magkano po ang inyong ibabayad? Ang charge ay 3% Ex. kung ang pinadala ay ₱1,000 ang charge po ay ₱30 ang total na babayaran ay ₱1,030. Dapat ang perang ibabayad ay pareho o mas mataas sa babayaran. </span>
        <input type="number" name="entry.401397408" placeholder="Input Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

    

           

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

I have 2 jquery scripts, both are working fine when i am using it individually. When i mixed them in one html page, the problem occurs.
here is my first function

```
    (function collapse(){
   jQuery('#query1,#order1,#pera-padala1,#gh-cash-out1,#paymaya-cash-in1,#claim-padala1,#gh-cash-in1,#E-

load1,#sanla1,#sanla-renew1,#tubos1,#bills-payment1,#repair1,#dl-install1,#paymaya-cash-out1').click( function(e) {
    jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
})();
```

the first function doesnt work when i've added this:

```
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 (function compute(){
    $('#padala-bayad').keyup(function(){
        $('#padala-result').text(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())+(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())*.03));
  });
  })();
```

When i remove the CDN  and the 2nd script, the first script is working.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: i didnt encounter any error sir, sorry for such newbie question i am still learning this language

Comment: I think that you will have to provide us with [minimal, reproducible demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will show us you issue

Comment: `.collapse()` method is bootstrap snippet, yet you (in your current example) load only jQuery

Comment: i've already edited it sir thanks for answering

Comment: I am sure that you are using bootstrap. Can you tell me which version of it you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not link the bootstrap css and js file...
Use this source code (it worked perfectly for me):

```html
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="query1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#query" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="query">
        Query/Concern/Suggestions
      </button>
    
    <div class="collapse" id="query">
      <div class="card card-body">
    sample
      </div>
    </div>
    
        <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="button" id="order1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#order" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="order">
        Advanced Order or For Delivery
      </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="order">
      <div class="card card-body">
      sample
      </div>
    </div>

<! ––pera-padala button ––>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="pera-padala1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#pera-padala" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pera-padala">
    Smart Pera Padala
  </button>

<! ––pera-padala ––>
<div class="collapse" id="pera-padala">
  <div class="card card-body">
  <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSeRxBdj_mH5afO7UGT9fb_o02sSbsFVf6LduIXH_3bRzYJsKg/formResponse">

      <div class="form-element">
        <span>A. Input ang Account Number ng Smart Padala na inyong papadalan.(Magsulat lamang ng 11 digits kung cellphone number at 16 digits kung account number</span>
       
      <div class="form-element">
        <span>B. Input ang amount na ipapadala  </span>
        <input name="entry.1812134286" id="padala-bayad"  type="number"  required="">
      </div>
      <br>
       <div class="form-element">
              <span>C. Total Babayaran: <span id="padala-result"></span> Magkano po ang inyong ibabayad? Ang charge ay 3% Ex. kung ang pinadala ay ₱1,000 ang charge po ay ₱30 ang total na babayaran ay ₱1,030. Dapat ang perang ibabayad ay pareho o mas mataas sa babayaran. </span>
        <input type="number" name="entry.401397408" placeholder="Input Amount" min="0" max="500000" step="any" required="">
      </div>
      <br>

    

           

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function collapse(){
  jQuery('#query1,#order1,#pera-padala1,#gh-cash-out1,#paymaya-cash-in1,#claim-padala1,#gh-cash-in1,#E-load1,#sanla1,#sanla-renew1,#tubos1,#bills-payment1,#repair1,#dl-install1,#paymaya-cash-out1')
  .click( function(e) {
      jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
  });
})();
</script>
<script>
 (function compute(){
    $('#padala-bayad').keyup(function(){
        $('#padala-result').text(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())+(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())*.03));
  });
  })();
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hello sir the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> solved my problem thank you very much I really appreciated your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are including jQuery again, remove the CDN from second script.

```
<script>
 (function compute(){
    $('#padala-bayad').keyup(function(){
        $('#padala-result').text(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())+(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())*.03));
  });
  })();
</script>
```

removed CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i remove the cdn, this script
 <script>
 (function compute(){
    $('#padala-bayad').keyup(function(){
        $('#padala-result').text(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())+(parseFloat($('#padala-bayad').val())*.03));
  });
  })();
</script>
doesnt work. When both of the 2nd script and the cdn are removed, the colapse are working again.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle for this and share the link

Comment: hello sir, the library added by sir Ar Rakin worked for me thank you very much :D